# Is there a difference between [&foo]{ ... } capture and [foo]{ ... } capture if 'foo' is a reference variable?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

For `foo` declared as `Foo& foo = ...;`, is there any difference between capture-by-value and capture-by-reference semantics for lambdas?

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit for clarity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.

`§5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda] p14`

> An entity is *captured by copy* if it is implicitly captured and the *capture-default* is `=` or if it is explicitly captured with a capture that does not include an `&`. For each entity captured by copy, an unnamed nonstatic data member is declared in the closure type. The declaration order of these members is unspecified. **The type of such a data member is** the type of the corresponding captured entity if the entity is not a reference to an object, or **the referenced type** otherwise.

So, if you capture an identifier that names a reference by value, you get a copy of the referenced object.

Comment: No, it's fine, since access to global variables is allowed. Output should be 2, provided you don't forget to initialize i with 0.

Comment: @John: Thanks, I totally overlooked the discrepancy between the capture and the used variable. Now getting [the expected error](http://liveworkspace.org/code/6f2da9b2b748758e5563fd424408b334). Also, global built-in types are zero-initialized. :)

Comment: Bleh, nevermind, that example is flawed, thanks @John. [This is correct](http://ideone.com/iXSk7)

Comment: @Xeo What is the behavior of [] with no capture specifiers? Is it = or & or some mixture?

Comment: @Eloff: An empty capture list will not capture anything.

Answer (score 16):

I think you have fallen to a common misconception... references are *aliases* to real objects. After initialization, any use of the reference is exactly equivalent to an use of the original object. If you consider this, the question makes little sense. If the reference **is** the object, then the behavior of `[foo](){}` will be exactly the same regardless of whether `foo` is an object or a reference to the object.

Comment: @Eloff: I don't think you understood what I said. Of course a *copy* and a *reference* are completely different things. What you seem not to grasp is that *after initialization* the reference is an **alias** to the original object. Whether there is an underlying pointer or not, the semantics are as if the *original* object was used. Your whole comment is off track.

Comment: Aha, that makes more sense! Sorry I read your answer wrong. I'll delete my comment so as to not confuse people.

Comment: @Eloff : Now it confuses people because they can't see what David was responding to. ;-]

Comment: Just to be clear, this argument is valid (in the general case) as long as we're only talking about the value of a reference, and not its type. If captures cared about type, then the fact it was a reference would matter; they don't though.

Comment: @GManNickG: The language is designed around the *illusion* that a reference is an *alias*, it even mentions that a reference does not need to take any *space* (for example in this question, `foo` will probably not take space). The underlying type to create that *illusion* is a reference type and it is not the type referenced, but in all contexts I can remember the language makes an effort to maintain that *illusion* including `sizeof(T&) == sizeof(T)`. Of course, the language could do otherwise, it would just not be C++

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I meant in cases like `int i; int& j = i;`, `decltype(i)` is `int` while `decltype(j)` is `int&`. Once you go into types instead of values (`sizeof` deals with values), it matters. Just to make sure your reasoning (which is excellent!) isn't misapplied, I mentioned it.

Comment: @GManNickG: `decltype` is a nice little beast... (btw, `decltype((j))` is also `int&`, just as an example of the quirks of that particular construct), and yes, this is a (the?) case where it matters. Now the claim that `sizeof` deals with values... the particular case I provide does not, `T` is a type, and `sizeof` is dealt at compile time based only on the *types* of the expressions. In the same way that `auto a = r;` has the same type whether `r` is a value or reference...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Fair enough, I did jump a bit too much. :) I think we both understand what the other is saying, and any hope of clarifying I was going after should be contained somewhere in these comments.